# Load Balancer and Proxy setup in AWS exhibits patchy performance

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

### Background

An HTTP request sent by an end-user to `www.stuff.com/things` is processed as follows:

1. Received by an application Load Balancer (the public load balancer) that load balances to an NGINX reverse proxy (Let's call this the security proxy).
2. The security proxy routes the request to a private application load balancer.
3. The private load balancer routes traffic based on the URL. if the url is `/things/...` then the request is routed to another NGINX proxy.
4. This second NGINX proxy (lets call this the `things` proxy) routes all requests to a classic load balancer.
5. The classic load balancer listens on ports 80 and 50000 and balances requests to instances hosting the `things` application.

So to recap: I have the *public load balancer*, the *security proxy*, the *private load balancer*, the *`things` proxy*, and the classic load balancer.

### The problem

When a user tries to visit `www.stuff.com/things`, they wait, and they wait, and they eventually receive an HTTP 504: gateway timeout. Or, the page loads immediately. Or, some elements load quickly while other hang.

### Debugging

I've tried issuing requests from several places in the chain:

1. `curl` the *classic load balancer*, response is **instantaneous**
2. `curl` the *`things` proxy*, response is **instantaneous**
3. `curl` the *private load balancer*, response is **instantaneous**
4. `curl` the *security proxy*, response is **instantaneous**
5. `curl` the *public load balancer*, response is **slooooow...** except when it's *fast*.

Perhaps I need to reconfigure my proxies?

### Proxy Configuration

The `things` proxy is configured as follows:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    server {
        location ^~ /proxycheck {
            return 200 'available';
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass ${PROXY_ADDRESS};
        }
    }
}
```

The *security proxy* is configured as follows:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    server {
        location ^~ /proxycheck {
            return 200 'available';
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass ${PROXY_ADDRESS};
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
            proxy_redirect default;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

In the future, the security proxy will check certificates. Until then, I've got this other problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do your error log files show when the request is slow?

Comment: I count five load balancers or proxies in the path of the request, could you outline why so many are necessary? Can you please edit your post to include a network diagram to explain the network and each node - CloudCraft have a good online tool.

Comment: @Tim sure! Will do this tonight. The long story short: The security proxy provides corporate security, the `things` proxy is required because I can't connect a load balancer to a load balancer (AFAIK, AWS doesn't provide a means of doing this). The public load balancer is required to balance load across security proxies, the private load balancer balances for applications (all but `things`, where it balances those proxies), and the `things` load balancer is required because an AWS application load balancer doesn't support non-http health checks or more than a single port.

Comment: Seems legit.  Turn on the logs for the ELBs.  You'll find the individual balancer node handling each request (each balancer node logs its own requests, with the node's IP in the filename, at least for Classic) and that may turn out to be useful.  Each ELB has a minimum of two nodes, which is something you may or may not be aware of, since it's done transparently.  You could have a problem with one but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this must have been a transient issue with AWS (related to the much-publicised fat-fingers incident), because I haven't been able to replicate it since posting this question.